# How to addforce to a single Ragdoll limb in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, ragdoll

I'm trying to make a Ragdoll that can move each limb individually. However when I try testing this on the Ragdoll's right leg, I get this error.

```
error CS1061:'CharacterJoint' does not contain a definition for 'AddForce' and no accessible extension method 'AddForce' accepting a first argument of type 'CharacterJoint' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I tried switching AddForce with SwingAxis which didn't change anything. I looked up the methods for Character Joint but couldn't find any that would make the leg bend at the joint.

```
public class rightLeg_movement : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public CharacterJoint cj;
     public float forwardForce = 2000f;

     void FixedUpdate()
     {
         if( Input.GetKey("m") )
         {
             cj.AddForce(forwardForce, 0, 0);
         }
     }
 }
```

All of the tutorials I looked up use an animation instead. However I plan on implementing an ai to do basic tasks with the Ragdoll(like learning to picking itself up, or learning to walk).

Comment: Is there a way for me to use JointMotor on a character joint?

Answer (score 2):

`CharacterJoint`s don't have support for driving the joints built-in.  You would be better off using [`ConfigurableJoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ConfigurableJoint.html)s instead. Once you configure the limits on the joints, you can use `ConfigurableJoint.angularXDrive` to configure the maximum angular  force it can apply and then `ConfigurableJoint.targetAngularVelocity` to configure the target angular velocity.

Also, it's recommended to call `Input` methods in `Update` instead of `FixedUpdate` where possible. From the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html):

> Note also that the Input flags are not reset until `Update`. It is suggested you make all the Input calls in the `Update` Loop.

Altogether, these changes might look like this for something like a knee joint that can only move around the local x axis:

```
public class rightLeg_movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public ConfigurableJoint cj;

    public float forwardForce = 2000f;
    public float backwardForce = 1000f;
    public float holdForce = 5000f;

    public float forwardVelocity = 2f;
    public float backwardVelocity = 1f;

    private bool isInputForward = false;
    private bool isInputBackward = false;

    void Start()
    {
        SetForwardJointMovement(holdForce, 0f);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        isInputForward = Input.GetKey("m");
        isInputBackward = Input.GetKey("n");

        if (isInputForward)
        {
            SetForwardJointMovement(forwardForce, forwardVelocity);
        }
        else if (isInputBackward)
        {
            SetForwardJointMovement(backwardForce, -backwardVelocity);
        }
        else
        {
            SetForwardJointMovement(holdForce, 0f);
        }
    }

    void SetForwardJointMovement(float force, float velocity)
    {
        JointDrive drive = new JointDrive();
        drive.maximumForce = force;
        drive.positionDamper = 1e10f;
        cj.angularXDrive = drive;

        cj.targetAngularVelocity = Vector3.left * velocity;
    }
}
```

The documentation for `ConfigurableJoint` is currently in very poor condition so apologies if something is off.

Comment: Excellent answer as usual, Ruzihm.

Comment: When I press m and or n nothing happens.

Comment: @DanieldosSantos I edited the answer to include setting the drive's `positionDamper` option to a high number.  That made it work for me! Good luck